# C# and entity framework - Casting object which is List<DynamicProxies...> to List<Entity>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, generics, converters

Scenario: I have a collection of entity framework entities using lazy loading and are therefor `DynamicProxies`. Then there is a a method that passes some selected items to an override I'm writing as `object`. I need to convert the `List<DynamicProxies.EntityABCD>` (which is actually passed as `object`) to a `List<Entity>`.

However casting the list this way

```
dropInfo.Data as List<MyEntity>
```

will return null. I can't even use the generic method `Cast<T>` because again the source list is passed as an `object`.

I also tried

```
dropInfo.Data as List<object>
```

but it still will return null.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Managed to get a cleaner list with

```
((IList)dropInfo.Data).Cast<MyEntity>()
```

However I still need to check for errors etc.

Comment: What exactly are you going to do with that `List`? Can't some covariant interface (like `IEnumerable<MyEntity>`, `IReadOnlyList<MyEntity>`) work for you?

Comment: Now I understood your problem. Is it possible to cast your `List<Proxy_123>` to `List<MyEntity>` before passing it to dragInfo? I suspect you somehow have to store supply the dragInfo with something (your List), so it can be passed back in `dropInfo.Data` when you drag and drop, so you could cast it before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **dynamic** quantifier for this, if you know your objects structure:

```
var result = ((List<dynamic>)dropInfo.Data).Select(ConvertToMyEntityMethod).ToList();

public static MyEntity ConvertToMyEntity(dynamic obj)
{
     return new MyEntity(){ SomeIntProperty = (int)obj.SomeIntProperty };
}
```

Dynamic allow you to get access to class members through reflection without compilation errors. This is really bad solution for performance, but very good if you work with MVVM bindings.

Comment: While this would look like something that fits my case, unfortunately casting to List<dynamic> won't work, while casting to the non-generic List will, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been awhile since this was asked, but figured that this would save  someone time.

You could just grab your entity and cast in a single operation assuming there's a direct cast available:

```
var data = datasource.Where(x => x.id == myID).Cast<MyEntity>().ToList();
```

`data` will now be typed as a `List<MyEntity>` and you should be good to go.